# Force page refresh to release memory

Tags: angularjs, memory-management, memory-leaks, single-page-application, angular-ui-router

Single page apps require careful management of events, DOM elements, and javascript objects in order to avoid leaks.

We're going to manage memory and squash leaks as best we can. That said, the application is large, uses many libraries, and could be left open for days at a time.

We need a safety valve.

I'm looking for ideas on how to unobtrusively trigger a page refresh in a single page app as a way to force the release of memory.

One idea is to detect when the user is idle for more than `N` minutes and do a refresh then, because it's unlikely to interrupt them. Much of the application state is saved in the URL using AngularJS ui-router, so this will work some of the time.

The problem is that while some state is in the router, not all of it will be. The user could have unsaved changes, or have some modal or flyout menu open which isn't in URL state. A solution could be to detect user changes and ban a refresh if any changes have taken place that aren't in the url. I don't see how to implement this generically though. Maybe we just put everything that's even a little bit important into URL state.

Another idea is to watch the application state change event `$stateChangeStart` and, every `Nth` time, do an actual browser navigation to that URL instead of just an app state change. This will never result in lost "sub-state", but will cause a slower page change response and a screen flicker. Maybe every 20 screen changes this is OK though.

Does anybody have any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea on unsaved changes and data:

I have an a single page app that in one section has several tabs each containing a form.  When each form becomes "dirty" it triggers a notification to the Main Controller, and sets a flag for that form.  When a user saves a particular form the flag becomes unset.  If the user tries to navigate away - before the route change occurs, it checks to see if any of the flags are set and then notifies the user via a modal that some particular information hasn't be saved.  The user can then decide whether to continue with the route change or go back and save the data.

This could easily be modified to perform the same check on page refresh and if there is unsaved data either cancel the page refresh or save the changes to the browser's local storage for recall after the page has finished refreshing.

Comment: I do sort of like the idea of setting `isDirty` on the state so the app knows not to try a refresh. This would require each potentially dirtying component to know (and the developer to remember) to set this flag, which has consequences that only appear after many minutes of user idleness.

Comment: I only set the flag when a form becomes "dirty" watching its `$dirty` property (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) I don't watch each individual field, although that maybe required in your application.  You could auto-save any "dirty" data and then refresh.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, if I was using forms heavily this would be a good system-wide place to tap in to it. But there's also expanding/collapsing folder trees, modals in layers, drop downs, and all sorts of other custom controls. Maybe this is still the right approach though. I can set the state "dirty" on any user interaction with a ui control.